# Laravel artisan always runs schedule

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I am working with Laravel 5.1, and something strange happens: whenever I execute an artisan command the schedule (app/Console/Kernel.php::schedule) is fired.
Does anybody know why this happens and if there is a way to prevent that to happen?

Comment: Check if you don't have the follow line in any cron file:

* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

regards!

Comment: Thanks, actually I have that cron set and I do need it. The problem was that the code within the schedule wasn't actually a schedule call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the code within the schedule wasn't actually a schedule call, I had something like

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    //do something
}
```

When I should have had something like this

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        //do something
    })->hourly();
}
```

Comment: Lucky you, I have the same problem, but I have an invocable class instead of a closure and this class has a constructor and this constructor is getting executed on each artisan command, and I did not notice it until it was too late. It is upsetting.